# Boto config file not being implemented

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, ubuntu-14.04, autoscaling

I am using an Ubuntu 14.04 server instance on AWS and I am having trouble moving a python script that works in the us-east-1 region to the Frankfurt eu-central-1 region. The script is to get the ip-addressess of all of the instances in a particular autoscaling group:

```
def get_autoscale_instance_ips(region, group):
    conn = boto.connect_ec2(region)
    as_conn = boto.connect_autoscale()    

    try:
        group = as_conn.get_all_groups(names=[group])[0]
        instances_ids = [i.instance_id for i in group.instances]
        reservations = conn.get_all_reservations(instances_ids)
        instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
        ip_addresses = [i.private_ip_address for i in instances]
```

According to the Boto documentation I need to change the autoscale endpoint from the default US region, by putting it in a boto config file either at /etc/boto.cfg for site-wide settings or ~/.boto for user-specific settings.

My config file just contains the following:

```
[Boto]
autoscale_endpoint = autoscaling.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
autoscale_region_name = eu-central-1
```

I have tried both of these options and in both cases the boto config file seems to ignored.

What am I doing wrong, I'm sure I've missed something obvious?